# How can I find all rows in master table with the same records in its child table?

Tags: sql-server

I need to find every record in TableA that has the same child records in TableB

for example :

tableA
keyA
1
2
3

tableB
keyA....keyB....valueB
1...........11...........4
1...........12...........5
2...........21...........4
2...........22...........5
3...........31...........4
3...........32...........6

So suppose I want to search for doubles.
It should return the two first rows in tableA because both these rows have the same amount of child records in tableB with the same values for valueB

the first row in tableA as 2 child records, one with valueB = 4 and one with valueB = 5
the second row in tableA also has 2 child records, and with the same values in field tableB
the third row also has 2 child records, but with different values in field valueB

so the 2 first rows in tableA should be returned if I search for doubles.

I tried this but it gives an error on the first subquery, it may not return more than one value :

```
select *
from   tableA t1
where  (select t2.valueB 
        from   tableB t2
        where  t2.keyA = 1
       )
       in 
       (select t3.valueB 
        from   tableB t3
        where  t3.keyA = t1.KeyA
       )
```

So, can this be done ?

EDIT : the output for my example should be
tableA
keyA
1
2

Edit 2 : rephrasing the question :
1. tableB is a childtable for tableA
2. there will be records in tableA that have records in tableB with the same values for field valueB as other records in tableA
3. I want to find these records.

EDIT: findings so far :

this query seems to produce what I need :

```
declare @keyA int = 1

select distinct r.keyA
from   tableA r
  inner join tableB eb on r.keyA = eb.keyA
where  (select count(1) from tableB eb1 where eb1.keyA = @keyA) = (select count(1) from tableB eb2 where eb2.keyA = r.keyA)
and    eb.valueB in (select eb4.valueB from tableB eb4 where eb4.keyA = @keyA)
```

The first where clause only allows master records where the number of child records are the same as for the first row in tableA. (all rows in tableA are found)
The second where clause only allows master records where the valueB of the child records are also present in the child records for the first row in tableA. (only first 2 rows in tableA are found)

The idea is to get all master records (tableA) that have the same amount of child records as the first row, and where all the values for valueB in these child records are also present in the child records for the first row of tableA.
Both where clauses combined should give me what I need, that is what I am hoping.

It seems to produce the correct result, but I would like some confirmation if its correct or wrong.

Comment: So suppose I want to search with value for KeyA = 1.
It should return the two first rows in tableA because both these rows have the same amount of child records in tableB with the same values for valueB  ??? is not clear,could you elaborate and provide some test output

Comment: I read your question like 3 times and I still can't figure out what you want to get. Please rephrase your question and I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
t1.A
from
t1
where exists(
           select 1 from t2 where t2.keya=t1.keya 
           group by t2.keya,t2.valueb
           having count(*)>1
            )
```

Comment: If I understand this correct you are using field keyA to find matches, but that is not the idea. The idea is to find all records in tableA that have the same amount of child records in tableB and all every child record in tableB should have the same value in field valueB. So the 3th record in tableA does not match because it does have the same amount of child records but with other values in field valueB. It seems very hard to explain exactly what I want

Comment: In tableB keyA value doesnt match your criteria right ?i f so my answer works

Comment: in tableB the value for keyA is not important, it does not have to match or not match. It is the field valueB that has to match

Comment: did you run my query ?,if that doesnt work,please update question with findings so far